# Two step dataframe rearrange in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I import a csv into a dataframe with this structure:

```
id brand p_1 p_2 p_3 p_4 p_5 
1  A    1   2   5   
2  B    2   3 
3  C    3
4  B    1
5  A    2
```

And I would like to first get it into this structure

```
p A B C
1 1 1 0
2 2 1 0
3 0 1 1  
4 0 0 0
5 1 0 0
```

So it counts all combinations of values *BUT* is also counts non existing ones such as 4 that does no appear YET is a value among 1 (min) and 5 (max), and this is the tricky part!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-(1:2)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  count(value, brand) %>%
  complete(value = 1:5, brand, fill = list(n=0)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = brand, values_from = n, values_fill = 0)
```

result

```
# A tibble: 5 × 4
  value     A     B     C
  <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     1     1     0
2     2     2     1     0
3     3     0     1     1
4     4     0     0     0
5     5     1     0     0
```

source data

```
df <- data.frame(
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L),
             brand = c("A", "B", "C", "B", "A"),
               p_1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L),
               p_2 = c(2L, 3L, NA, NA, NA),
               p_3 = c(5L, NA, NA, NA, NA),
               p_4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
               p_5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
)
```